# How to measure the cumulative performance of multi-step parallel operations in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, parallel-processing

**TLDR** When running a batch of 3 step functions in parallel, what is the easiest way to measure the total amount of time spent on step 1, step 2, and step 3 across all parallel operations?

**Details**

Suppose that I have some code that hits a rest endpoint, processes the data, and then jams the result into a database.

```
async function workFunction(id) {
    const url = buildUrl(id);

    const post = await fetchData(url);      // step 1
    const output = await crunchData(post);  // step 2
    await writeData(url, output);           // step 3

    console.log('done with ', id);
}
```

I have "bunch" of ID's to process, so I run the processing in parallel.

```
const idList = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const promises = idList.map(async (id) => {
    await workFunction(id);
});

const result = Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log('All work done'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Something went wrong'));
```

This works, but suppose that I run into a bottleneck that is slowing things down. I want to investigate which part of the worker func is the main culprit, so I butcher my beautiful worker function with some manual code to time each step and add the result to an accumulator.

```
let totalFetchTime = 0;
let totalCrunchTime = 0;
let totalDatabaseWriteTime = 0;

async function workFunction(id) {
    const url = buildUrl(id);
    let startTime, endTime;

    startTime = performance.now();
    const post = await fetchData(url);
    endTime = performance.now();
    totalFetchTime += (endTime - startTime);

    startTime = endTime;
    const output = await crunchData(post);
    endTime = performance.now();
    totalCrunchTime += (endTime - startTime);

    startTime = endTime;
    await writeData(url, output);
    endTime = performance.now();
    totalDatabaseWriteTime += (endTime - startTime);
}
```

This works, but it is ugly as sin. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing? The [performance measurement APIs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/perf_hooks.html) look like they are geared for this sort of thing, but I'm not sure the best way to to accumulation across parallel workers.

Complete code snippet

```js
const database = {};
const performance = window.performance;


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper routines. Nothing interesting here
async function writeData(key, value) {
  console.log(`writeDB called with ${key} = ${value}'`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      database[key] = value;
      console.log(`committed DB write to database ${key}=${value}`);
      resolve(key);
    }, 500 + Math.random() * 500);
  });
}

async function fetchData(url) {
  console.log(`Fetching URl ${url}`);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(`Worker resolving url ${url}`);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Worker REJECTING url ${url}`);
    throw e;
  }
}

async function crunchData(input) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const result = input.body.split(/(\s+)/).length;
      resolve(result);
    }, 50 + Math.random() * 50);
  });
}

function buildUrl(id) {
  return `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main processing code.
let totalFetchTime = 0;
let totalCrunchTime = 0;
let totalDatabaseWriteTime = 0;

async function workFunction(id) {
  // TODO: make this function less ugly
  const url = buildUrl(id);
  let startTime, endTime;

  startTime = performance.now();
  const post = await fetchData(url);
  endTime = performance.now();
  totalFetchTime += (endTime - startTime);

  startTime = endTime;
  const output = await crunchData(post);
  endTime = performance.now();
  totalCrunchTime += (endTime - startTime);

  startTime = endTime;
  await writeData(url, output);
  endTime = performance.now();
  totalDatabaseWriteTime += (endTime - startTime);
}

const idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const promises = idList.map(async(id) => {
  await workFunction(id);
});

function logPerformanceStats() {
  console.log(`Total fetch time : ${totalFetchTime.toFixed(1)} ms`);
  console.log(`Total crunch time : ${totalCrunchTime.toFixed(1)} ms`);
  console.log(`Total write time : ${totalDatabaseWriteTime.toFixed(1)} ms`);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

const result = Promise.all(promises)
  .then(logPerformanceStats)
  .catch((e) => console.log('Something went wrong : ', e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, which is basically turning the basic tests you already perform into a `class` that allows the creation of timers like `objects` + adding an extra function to get more `readable` times from a human point of view.

````
/**
 * Description of Class PerfTimer
 * 
 * this class allow to create objects 
 * that can be used through their methods to measure execution time
 * in a more straightforward way 
 */
class PerfTimer {
    #startTime;
    #endTime;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    constructor() {
        this.#startTime = performance.now();
        this.#endTime = undefined;
    }

    // FUNCTIONS
    /**
     * ```
     * PerfTimer.reset()
     * ```
     * - resets a PerfTimer object, by reaffecting the following values for its private properties:
     *   - `#startTime`: current time at function call (in ms)
     *   - `#endTime`: undefined
     */
    reset = () => {
        this.#startTime = performance.now();
        this.#endTime = undefined;
    }
    /**
     * ```
     * PerfTimer.stop() 
     * ```
     * - stops the actual PerfTimer object, 
     * by affecting the current time (in ms) to the private property `#endTime`
     * 
     * _use `performance.now()`_
     */
    stop = () => this.#endTime = performance.now();
    /**
     * ```
     * PerfTimer.resume()
     * ```
     * - resume the actual PerfTimer object,
     * by unsetting the value of the private property `#endTime`
     * which may have been set with a previous `PerfTimer.stop()` call.
     * 
     */
    resume = () => this.#endTime = undefined;
    /**
     * ```
     * PerfTimer.elapsedTime(unit = 'auto', returnNumber = false)
     * ```
     * - returns the elapsed time since the PerfTimer object creation or it's last reset.
     * - 1st argument allows to change the unit of the returned value.
     * - 2nd argument allows to select the type of the returned value between `Number` or `String` \
     * this will only work when `unit` value equals `"ms"` or `"s"`
     * 
     * **-- Arguments :**
     * @param {'auto' | 'ms' | 's'} unit a `string` that allows to specify the **unit** of the returned value \
     * accepted options are : 
     * - `"auto"` **[default value]**
     * - `"ms"`
     * - `"s"`
     * @param {boolean} returnNumber a `boolean` that allows to specify the **type** of the returned value between `string` or `number`, \
     * note that it **only works** if `unit` value is different from `"auto"` otherwise it will always return a `string`
     * - `true` returned value will be a `number` 
     * - `false` returned value will be a `string` **[default value]**
     * 
     * **-- Return Value :** 
     * @returns {string | number} `string` or `number`  
     * - `string` : \
     * when `unit == "auto"` or if `returnNumber == false` 
     * 
     * - `number`: \
     * when `unit != "auto"` **and** `returnNumber == true`
     */
    elapsedTime = (unit = 'auto', returnNumber = false) => {

        let elapsedTime; // will receive the elapsed time in ms (!! not rounded !!)

        if (this.#endTime == undefined) {
            let endTime = performance.now();
            elapsedTime = endTime - this.#startTime;
        } else {
            elapsedTime = this.#endTime - this.#startTime;
        }


        if (unit == 'ms') { // if unit is "ms" will return the exact value of execution time in ms
            if (returnNumber == false)
                return elapsedTime + ' ms';

            else if (returnNumber == true)
                return elapsedTime;
            
        } else
        if (unit == 's') {
            if (returnNumber == false)
                return ( Math.round(elapsedTime) / 1000 ) + ' s';

            else if (true)
                return ( Math.round(elapsedTime) / 1000 ); // returns the ms value (rounded) divided by 1000

        } else
        if (unit == 'auto') {
            return sToDHMS( Math.round( Math.round(elapsedTime) / 1000 ) );
        }

        
    }

} // END OF PerfTimer

/**
 * ```
 * function sToDHMS(seconds) { ... }
 * ```
 * - return a string which represent the provided time in `seconds` in a more readable way, \
 * goes up to **days** ranging from **seconds**. 
 * - returned format vary upon the `time` value, defined formats are : 
 *   - `'X+ days, XXh XXm XXs'`
 *   - `'XXh XXm XXs'`
 *   - `'XXm XXs'`
 *   - `'XXs'`
 * 
 *   _**note :** there are no filling `0` so sometimes a `XX` may result in a `X`_ 
 * 
 * **-- Argument :**
 * @param {number} seconds `number` in seconds 
 * 
 * **-- Return Value :** 
 * @returns {string} `string` format will vary upon the provided `seconds` value
 * - **_days_**  (`seconds >= 86400`) : \
 * returned string format is `'X+ days, XXh XXm XXs'` 
 * - **_hours_** (`seconds >= 3600`) : \
 * returned string format is `'XXh XXm XXs'`
 * - **_minutes_** (`seconds >= 60`) : \
 * returned string format is `'XXm XXs'`
 * - **_seconds_** (`seconds < 60`) : \
 * returned string format is `'XXs'`
 */
function sToDHMS(seconds) {  

    if (seconds >= 86400) { // days detected

        let d = Math.floor( seconds / 86400 ), // days
            h = Math.floor( ( seconds % 86400 ) / 3600 ), // hours 
            m = Math.floor( (( seconds % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ), // minutes
            s = (( seconds % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60; // seconds

        if (d == 1) 
            return `${d} day, ${h}h ${m}m ${s}s`;
        else 
            return `${d} days, ${h}h ${m}m ${s}s`;

    } else
    if (seconds >= 3600) { // hours detected

        let h = Math.floor( seconds / 3600 ), // hours
            m = Math.floor( ( seconds % 3600 ) / 60 ), // minutes
            s = ( seconds % 3600 ) % 60; // seconds

        return `${h}h ${m}m ${s}s`;

    } else 
    if (seconds >= 60) { // minutes detected

        let m = Math.floor( seconds / 60 ), // minutes 
            s = seconds % 60; // seconds

        return `${m}m ${s}s`;
        
    } else 
    if (seconds < 60) { // only seconds
        return `${seconds}s`;
    }

} //
````

**How to use :** 
A call to the `PerfTimer` constructor will create an instance of the class which is an `object` that contains **2** private properties :

- `#startTime` initialized with a call to `performance.now()`
- `#endTime` initialized with `undefined`

it also includes the following functions:

- `PerfTimer.reset()` :
  A call to this method will reassign `#startTime` value with a new call to performance.now() and set back `#endTime` to `undefined`.
- `PerfTimer.stop()` :
  will assign `#endTime` value with a new call to `performance.now()`
- `PerfTimer.resume()` :
  will set back `#endTime` value to `undefined`
- `PerfTimer.elapsedTime(unit = 'auto', returnNumber = false)` :

  - returns the elapsed time since the `PerfTimer` *object creation* or *it's last reset*.
  - 1st argument allows to change the unit of the returned value. 
     options are: `'auto'` | `'ms'` | `'s'` if set to `'auto'` the `sToDHMS()` method will be called to transform the result
  - 2nd argument allows to select the type of the returned value between `Number` or `String`
    *this will only work when `unit` value equals `"ms"` or `"s"`*

**Example of utilisation :**

```
  let perf = new PerfTimer(); // #startTime is defined from creation
  const post = await fetchData(url);
  totalFetchTime = perf.elapsedTime(); // default 'auto' && returnNumber = false

  perf.reset(); // reset #startTime
  const output = await crunchData(post);
  totalCrunchTime = perf.elapsedTime('ms', true);

  perf.reset();
  await writeData(url, output);
  totalDatabaseWriteTime = perf.elapsedTime('s', true);
```